# Are massless objects immovable?

Tags: physics

I didn't think so, but I'm looking at a course problem,

> A string of length $L$ and line density $\rho$ is under a tension $\rho c^2$. Its transverse displacement is $y(x,t)$. The string is fastened to rings at $x=0$ and $x=L$. The masses of the
> rings can be neglected, and they slide on two smooth fixed wires at $x=0$ and $x=L$, one ring being on each wire; the wires are parallel to $0y$. By considering the equations of motion of the rings, show that $$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=0$$ at $x=0$ and $x=L$ for all $t$. By seeking separable solutions, find the normal modes of vibration.

The given solution begins,

> Consider either ring. Since each has zero mass, \begin{align}
> & \text{Newton’s Second Law} \\
> \implies & x\ddot{y} = \text{vertical component of force} = \pm F\sin{\psi} \\ \implies & \sin{\psi}=0 \text{ at } x=0,L
> \end{align} but \begin{align}
> &\psi\ll1 \\
> \implies&\sin(\psi)\approx\tan(\psi)=\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} \\
> \implies & \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=0 \text{ at } x=0,L.
> \end{align}

Doesn't this reasoning imply that any object with negligible mass is immovable? Couldn't one equally validly reason that $$\ddot{y}=\frac{F\sin{\psi}}{0}=\infty$$?

I also don't really understand why the $x$ in $x\ddot{y}$ seems to be mass.

**ETA:** My interest is in finding the problem in the argument rather than answering the title question experimentally.

Comment: Photons are massless, and they move ***really*** fast.

Comment: @LeeMosher OK; can you spot a problem in the reasoning? I'm assuming that rejecting the premise of the question on experimental grounds won't get me marks in an exam.

Comment: @mjc This is simply a result of Newtonian Mechanics being an incomplete theory, since by Newton's Law if $m = 0$ then $F = 0$ so there's no kinematics. You need relativistic physics to make sense of massless particles having energy

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I think that's probably the answer I'm looking for. The comment is enough for me, but if you care to write it as an answer I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: For a particle of mass $m$ acting under a force $F$ you have the balance $m\dot v = F$. Reducing $m$ means $\dot v$ will be larger, so yes it's moving. At some point though, relativistic considerations kick in.

Comment: @Aruralreader I think that's the $\ddot{y}=\frac{F\sin{\psi}}{0}=\infty$ argument I make towards the end of the OP, but the reasoning in the given solution is the opposite.